# Parallel website requests stuck in pending state since activating HTTP/2

Tags: apache, ssl, https, http2

I'm using an Ansible Playbook for my local dev server. I just added HTTP/2 support and now, a few resources stuck in pending state:

[image]

Opening something like `info.php` just works fine.

I'm using Apache 2.4.23, mod_http2 and this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot {{ apache.docroot }}
  ServerName {{ apache.servername }}

  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sxs.dev.key
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sxs.dev.cert

  <Directory {{ apache.docroot }}>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Update

I minified my `app.js` and now it works. Is there something like a file limit? Chrome says that the "request not finished yes" when using the unminified version.

Comment: I have the same issue. Getting a lot of heat for it. Good to know its not just IIS/.net that is having the issue.